# fastcgi to cgi in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cgi

I'm a newbie at sql. I have a new website on dreamhost and it keeps going down for minutes or hours a day. It's a simple wordpress site with 3 standard basic plugins. Its really simple.

it keeps going down for minutes or hours a day and the dreamhost guys told me to change the php version from fastcgi to cgi.

problem is i have no idea how to do this. Ive poked around the phpadmin but scared of touching anything, and searching online gives me a load of code that im not even going to pretend to understand.

any noob friendly advice?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! found it in the cpanel ...apologies.